# Hotels cancellation policy J-2, J-25, etc

Tags: france, bookings, hotels, cancellations

A hotel in France has the following cancellation policy (translated from French):

- Reservation for 1 to 4 nights: Cancel on the day of arrival without fees [...].
- Reservation for 5 to 27 nights: Cancel without fees until J-2, noon (GMT+1h). [...]
- Reservation for 28 nights and over: Cancel without fees until J-15, noon (GMT+1h). [...]

Does J-n mean a period of n days before the booked stay begins, or does it mean n days after the stay has begun? I think that it is most likely the former, but wanted to make sure. Would appreciate an answer from someone who knows for sure. An internet search didn't give me much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your intuition is right, it is before.
The minus indicates that you should substract. If you wanted to add you would use a plus.

If today (2021-12-24) was for some reason important to you, today would be the day J (le jour J in French).
J-2 would be 2021-12-22 and J+2 would be 2021-12-26.
The use of minus is much more common than the use of plus.

So to specify a bit regarding your question, it doesn't specify a period but a specific day. From the context I deduce that the day J is your arrival date at the hotel.

Comment: I thought it was a short dash, not a minus :)

Comment: *Le jour J* is equivalent to *the D-day*  in English (in its general meaning, not the Normandy landings).

Comment: @WoJ If J is a variable representing the day, it's closer to "Day D".

Comment: @Acccumulation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Day_(military_term)